# How can I add a JS variable into error message and keep one font ID tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a form with the following error message. This error message functions properly, so I'm sharing that first then showing what I'm trying to change next:

```js
if (thing is true) {
    $(this).parents("table:first")
    .prop("disabled",true)
    .css({'background-color' : 'lightgray'})
    .after("<font color = red id=error3><strong>*</strong> Please check that your start and end dates are between June 15, 2018 and November 30, 2019. The Start Date may not be greater than the End Date.</font>");
}
```

I want to change the error message to include dates provider by the user earlier in the form. When I use concatenation, it looks like this:

```js
if (thing is true) {
    // example dates provided by user
    cysd = $("#id_currentyearstartdate").val();
    cyed = $("#id_currentyearenddate").val();
    // let's say cysd is January 1, 2018 and cyed is December 31, 2018

    $("input#next-submit-button")
    .prop("disabled",true)
    .css({'background-color' : 'lightgray'})
    .after("<font color = red id=error2><br>Please resolve any errors above before continuing. <br><strong>*</strong> Check that your start and end dates are between </font>" + cysd + "<font color = red id=error2> and </font>" + cyed + "<font color = red id=error2>. The Start Date may not be greater than the End Date.</font>");
```

Where I messed up is that, in the original error message, I had a single error message with the font id "error2." This allowed me to easily add or remove the error message on the right conditions.

I don't know how to include the variable values *within* the actual error message text or font tag, so that when id=error2 will still refer to the *entire* string "Please check that your start and end dates are between January 1, 2018 and December 31, 2018. The Start Date may not be greater than the End Date.

Comment: `<font>` tags are deprecated. Should use css instead

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just put it in the same tag...

```
.after("<font color = red id=error2><br>Please resolve any errors above before continuing. <br><strong>*</strong> Check that your start and end dates are between " + cysd + ". The Start Date may not be greater than the End Date.</font>");
```

You could alternatively use [template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) instead of concating which is a little easier because you don't have to worry abut mixing up your quotes. Wrap your string in backticks (`) and put your variables in curlies preceeded by a `$`.

```
.after(`<font color = red id=error2><br>Please resolve any errors above before continuing. <br><strong>*</strong> Check that your start and end dates are between ${cysd}. The Start Date may not be greater than the End Date.</font>`);
```

Either way tho, you should not be using `font` tags - [they're obsolete](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/font). Use css and span tags instead.

```
.after(`<span style=color:red id=error2><br>Please resolve any errors above before continuing. <br><strong>*</strong> Check that your start and end dates are between ${cysd}. The Start Date may not be greater than the End Date.</span>`);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a [Template Literal](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) and put variable values into your strings using dollar sign and curly braces. E.g.: ${cysd}

```
$("input#next-submit-button")
.prop("disabled",true)
.css({'background-color' : 'lightgray'})
.after(`<font color="red" id="error2"><br>Please resolve any errors above before continuing. <br><strong>*</strong> Check that your start and end dates are between ${cysd} and ${cyed}. The Start Date may not be greater than the End Date.</font>`);
```

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you wrap the whole message in a `div` with `id="error2"`:

```
<style>
    #error2 {
        color: 'red'
    }

    .error_date {
        color: 'blue'
    }
</style>

$("input#submit-button")
    .prop("disabled",true)
    .after("<div id='error2'>" +
        "Please resolve any errors above before continuing.<br/>" +
        "<strong>*</strong> Check that your start and end dates are between <span class='error_date'>" + cysd + "</span> and <span class='error_date'>" + cyed + "</span>." +
        "The Start Date may not be greater than the End Date.</div>");
```

Comment: JS strings don't allow unescaped linebreaks. You  got some funky quotes there too.

Comment: quotes and linebreaks fixed - the linebreaks were only there for code readability